# How to specify default extensions while running gitpods' openvscode-server

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitpod, visual-studio-code-server

Using https://github.com/gitpod-io/openvscode-server is there a way to set default VSCode extensions using their Docker command? (`docker run -it --init -p 3000:3000 -v "$(pwd):/home/workspace:cached" gitpod/openvscode-server`)

Answer (score 2):

you can pass extra arguments to your docker command to install extensions, for example:

```bash
docker run -it --init -p 3000:3000 gitpod/openvscode-server --install-extension gitpod.gitpod-theme --install-extension vscodevim.vim --start-server
```

Feel free to drop by our community at https://gitpod.io/chat !